# Downloading file using Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I am trying to do a little project where I download a file through the browser. I want to use Tomcat for that.

I installed and ran Tomcat, on addresss http://localhost:8080/ I have main Tomcat site. I placed file `test.txt` into `webapps/test/` and I am trying to enter http://localhost:8080/test/test.txt, but it does not work. All I see is `Error 404, requested resource is not available`. What do I  I need to do? Create some application not only directory in webapps? Or should I set some mapping from URL to file?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to create a web app in a war file and deploy it through the /manager interface.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html

Comment: In case you just want to server static files, I'd rather go with a standard web server, e.g. Apache HTTP server or nginx.